# tooltip with close button and 3 second delay to hide jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to close buttton tooltip and 3 seconds delay to hide if input is empty. 3 seconds delay is working but close button is not working if I erase the delay and fadeout in id #closetooltip button to close is working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYh2n.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<html>
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#firstname").blur(function(){
                   var firstname = $(this).val();
                   if(firstname == ""){
                       $(this).removeClass("w3-border-blue").addClass("w3-border-red");
                     
                       $("#closetooltip").fadeIn("fast").delay(3000).fadeOut("fast");
                       $("#hero").html("<b>Firstname is Empty!<b>");
                       $("#shiwicon").show("fast");
                      $("#closex").click(function(){
                           $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
                       });
                      
                      }
                 
               });
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


 <form >
                        
                        <div class="w3-col l4 w3-margin-bottom w3-margin-right w3-tooltip w3-round- w3-display-container" id="colorChange" style="">
                            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="w3-border w3-border-blue w3-input w3-round-large" 
                                   style="outline: none;" placeholder="First name"><i style="font-size:24px; padding-top: 8px; padding-right: 5px;color: red;display: none" id="shiwicon" class="fa w3-display-topright">&#xf12a;</i>
                            <div class="" id="toollx">
                        <div class="w3-round-large w3-red w3-text w3-padding-16 w3-padding-large w3-display-container" id="closetooltip" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:35px;width: 100%;display: none"> 
                            <span id="hero">    </span>
                            <span id="closex" class="w3-round-large w3-button w3-hover-red w3-hover-text-black w3-red w3-display-topright" style="padding: 5px">&times;</span>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                            </div><br><br><br><br>
                        
                    <div class="w3-col l4 w3-margin-bottom w3-tooltip w3-round- w3-display-container" id="colorChange2" style="">
                        <input onblur="loadData()" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="w3-input w3-round-large w3-border w3-border-blue" style="outline: none" placeholder="Last name"><i style="font-size:24px; padding-top: 8px; padding-right: 5px; display: none" id="shiwicon2" class="fa w3-display-topright">&#xf12a;</i>
                       <div class="w3-round-large w3-text w3-red w3-padding-16 w3-padding-large w3-display-container" id="closetooltip2" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:35px;width: 100%;display: none"> 
                            <span id="lastname2" style="display:none">    </span>
                            <span class="w3-round-large w3-button w3-hover-red w3-hover-text-black w3-red w3-display-topright" style="padding: 5px" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'">&times;</span>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
<body>





</body>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: close button tooltip and 3 seconds delay to hide tooltip sir

Comment: what does it mean to "close a button"?

Comment: 3 seconds delay to hide tooltip is working but close button is not working   with the id of closebutton

Comment: i will press the button to close automatically not to wait 3 seconds

Comment: your "close button" is hidden, how do you make it visible so that user can click it?

Comment: but it show while i call the div tooltiptext id

Comment: You know that you're hiding `#tooltiptext` with `$(this).parent().hide("fast");` right? Did you mean to hide `#tooltip`?

Comment: i call the div with the child span? to fadein? does it will show the two child?

Comment: if i display block in the id of closebutton it will show x in input

Comment: li have the picture sir

Comment: i can close the button but if i erase delay().fadeout()

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to show up the close button as well as this is not getting shown on blur.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstname").blur(function(){
      var firstname = $(this).val();

   if(firstname == ""){
       $("#tooltiptext").fadeIn("fast", function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#tooltiptext").fadeOut("fast");  <== can use setTimeout function
                },3000)
       })
       $("#textmessage").html("<b>Firstname is Empty!<b>");
           }
        });
           $("#closebutton").click(function(){
               $(this).parent().hide();
           });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">
<input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="firstname">
<div id="tooltiptext" class="tooltiptext" style="display:none">
<span  id="textmessage"></span>
<span id="closebutton">x</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but  it will hide the x  only not the tooltiptext  sir

Comment: if i erase the delay in and fadeout in id tooltiptext it will close button but not the 3 seconds delay